# Changing background of TextView (Android 4.4)

Tags: android, mobile, colors, background

I have a `TextView` that is declared in XML by:

```
<TextView 
 android:id="@+id/myTextControl" 
 android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
 android:layout_margin="1dp" 
 android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
 android:layout_weight="1" 
 android:background="#FFFFFF" 
 android:text="MyText"/>
```

I try to change the background programmatically:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
TextView tv;
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextControl);
tv.setText("MyText Has Changed!");
tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

But it results in my control not changing colour at all, no matter what I set the colour as. It happens on actual hardware and in the emulator also.

Comment: is the text shown or not?

Comment: the background color does not change, but the text does?

Comment: The text changes but the Bg does not.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code it works fine but after I specify

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution:
I changed the version of android and recompiled it for 4.3 instead of 4.4 and the problem was solved for some reason.